# /dev/kvm is missing from system supporting kvm-virtualization

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, gentoo, qemu

I'm trying to enable kvm-virtualization for Android virtual devices. In order to do so, I followed [this guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU) and did the following:

1. Checked, if kvm-virtualization is available:

   ```
   user $ grep --color -E "vmx|svm" /proc/cpuinfo
   flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt
   ```
2. Enabled Vt-x in BIOS;
3. Added support in kernel via setting `CONFIG_KVM` and `CONFIG_KVM_INTEL` modules as built-in modules in `genkernel --menuconfig all`;
4. Emerged package `app-emulation/qemu`.

However, when I try to run it, I get the following:

```
user $ qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
```

And as title says, there is no `/dev/kvm` file. How can I fix this problem?

EDIT: [/proc/cpuinfo content](https://gist.github.com/arkadiytehgraet/25f7a9d6d2a10101cda4)

Comment: paste the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` please.

Comment: @schaiba added /proc/cpuinfo contents

Comment: What does `dmesg | fgrep -i kvm` say?

Comment: @siblynx well, it's empty

Comment: Sounds like you still running an old kernel or you'd configured kvm support as a loadable modules rather than statically linked into kernel...

Comment: Are you sure that KVM is built-in rather than a module? `grep CONFIG_KVM .config` in the kernel build tree, check that it's `=y`, or load the module(s) if you see `=m`. Do you have KVM in the kernel? `find /sys -name 'kvm*'` Does KVM work if you create the device manually? `mknod /dev/kvm c 10 232`, adjust permissions as desired.